# Chrome malforms li > a > ul > li > a HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-lists, chromium

Chrome is changing the structure of my HTML for seemingly no reason, removing the second level anchor tag generates the expected html and replacing it with a div or any other tag also works fine. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfbx76q2/)

Written code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      Whatup
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/test/">Yo</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Interpreted code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      Whatup
    </a>
    <ul>
      <a href="/"></a>
      <li>
        <a href="/"></a>
        <a href="/test/">Yo</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Example working code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      Whatup
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>Yo</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can not nest links in HTML. Chrome does not change this for “no reason”, but to correct the mistake _you made_.

Comment: And FYI, _validating_ your code can help you figure out stuff like this before you ask. https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another `a` in the inner list. This is what's causing the inner `ul` to break out of the outer `a`, since you cannot have an `a` within another `a` (otherwise, the browser doesn't know how to handle clicking the inner `a`).

In other words, it's not Chrome that's malforming your HTML — your HTML is malformed to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, I thought my HTML might be malformed somehow but it didn't even occur to me that a > * > a wouldn't be valid, that makes perfect sense. I will accept your answer when I can

Comment: @Nbody Nbody: In fairness, it's hard to spot just by looking at the markup. This is why validating your markup regularly is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. You should use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

From the specification for [the a element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> Content model: Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

Links are interactive content (people are expected to click on them to load a new page).

The browser is attempting to recover from your error.